# Printing problems from Vista laptop to network HP OfficeJet 8500A

Tags: windows-vista, network-printer, hp-officejet

I have a network with some computers connected to it; one of those machines is a laptop running Vista.

When I try to print from this laptop the documents just seem to pile up in the spool directory on this laptop. The first one saying "Error - Printing" and the others just stuck after it.

I already tried to reboot the laptop and to `net stop spooler` and delete the files in `%windir\system32\spool\*.*` and then `net start spooler`.

It cleared the spooler's queue but the next time I tried to print it just got stuck again.

Other machines on the network can print properly on the same printer and it does not seem like a connectivity issue either as I can get to the printers web interface from the laptop in question.

I'm looking for ideas on how to resolve this or any information on when to look to find out what is the error that is reported by the queue/spooler.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
I just wanted to add that it did print up till recently, and nope AFAIK I did not install anything new on that machine.

Comment: Never had any issues printing from Vista with this printer (having the Plus version; but that shouldn't make any difference). How did you install the printer? Did you just add it as a network printer or did you install the drivers manually? Is the printer shown as online? Some firewall blocking it?

Comment: Mine is a HP Officejet Pro 8500 A910". I am not 100% sure how I installed it. most likely I used the drivers from the disk that came with the printer. when queue is empty printer status shows "Ready". also tried to stop the windows firewall but it did not help.

Comment: Yeah, that's the full name. The "Plus" just has an ADF. That's it. I'd try to uninstall all drivers, then just add the printer as a network printer. Vista should then download the drivers on its own (either from the printer or  from the web).

Comment: Is there no way to know what error is actually reported?

Comment: You might find something in Windows' system/event logs.

Comment: nope, I looked at the logs and found nothing.
any special way you suggest for uninstalling the drivers?

Comment: Remove the printer, then check Add/Remove programs.